# "ordering" levels in a multilevel mixed-effects linear regression

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

This may be the dumbest (but is also probably the quickest) question about multilevel mixed-effects linear regressions ever asked.

In a multilevel mixed-effects linear regression, do the different levels need to be "ordered" according to size?

Allow me to explain: I am running a multilevel mixed-effects linear regression model on a dataset of congressional bills voting on over several congresses (basically the 93rd through 113th Congress). I have independent variables that are at two levels: one is for each bill in the dataset, and one is for each Congress in the dataset. I am interested in the impact of the congress-level predictors. I do not have any real interest in the bill-level predictors -- these are in the model as control variables.

Does it make sense to set up the model such that the the first set of variables are the congress-level variables, with random-effects parameters estimated for each bill and bill-level variable. The unit of analysis here IS each bill. For example (STATA code):

```
mixed depend_variable congresslevel_indvariablee || bill: billlevel_indvariables
```

Or does the model need to be set up with the "smaller" level first:

```
mixed depend_variable billlevel_indvariables || congress: congresslevel_indvariables
```

I ask primarily because I am interested in calculating marginal effects for the congress-level variable, but cannot calculate marginal effects for random-effects parameters in the mixed model.

Any guidance is well appreciated.

Comment: I do not know STATA, and this seems to be more about the software than the statistics of it, but have you tried running both models and seeing if they differ from one another?

Comment: I have run both, but I do not know if the results are comparable. For instance, with any congress-level variable, with the first way of running the models the output is a coefficient, but for the second way the output is a random-effects parameter estimate. I don't know if those can be compared.

Comment: I am not sure if you found a response, but in any case, this video and its part-2 may help answer your question- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KALxDwwqX1A